# Sun Identity Manager 7.1 & Sun Identity Manager 8.1 Availability

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Could someone tell me if the 7.1 and 8.1 releases of Sun Identity Manager (Oracle Waveset) are still available? And if they are, where can I download them? I have looked for some links but no results found. I need them to upgrade Sun Identity Manager 6.0.

Thank you very much